# jQuery table sorter - adding 2 or more custom textExtractions

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

for those of you who aren't farmiliar with jquery tablesorter:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Now, I managed to create a custom text extraction based on an image alt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#MainTable").tablesorter({
            textExtraction:function(s){
            if($(s).find('.logo').length == 0) return $(s).text();
            return $(s).find('.logo').attr('alt');
            } 
      });
});
```

But the kicker is that I want to use another textExtraction but have no idea how to achieve that, tried putting it everywhere possible, any help would be appreciated, the 2nd custom extractor I want is:

```
        textExtraction:function(s){
        if($(s).find('.big').length == 0) return $(s).text();
        return $(s).find('.big').attr('id');
        }
```

They both work well individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse your functions into one.

```
function (s) {
  var $s = $(s);

  var logo = $s.find('.logo')[0];
  if (logo) return logo.alt;

  var big  = $s.find('.big')[0];
  if (big) return big.id;

  return $s.text();
}
```